# Add facebook meta tags to head within shortcode (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, head

In the shortcode function I am creating the facebook meta tags. But I have no idea how I can add these to the head.

It will look something like this:

```
<!-- FACEBOOK METAS -->
<meta property="og:url" content="<<-- voertuig_url_cms -->>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<<-- merk -->> <<-- model -->> <<-- uitvoering -->> - <<-- bedrijf -->> - <<-- plaats -->>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<<-- voertuig_foto1 -->>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<<-- bedrijf -->>" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="nl_NL" />
<!-- FACEBOOK METAS -->
```

In the shortcode I will replace every <<-- -->> and then I should add this to the head.

If this is for example a string. Does anybody have an idea to add this to the head?

Comment: [Does this help?](https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-meta-tags/)

Comment: I am making a plugin myself. So it must work without any other plugin

Comment: Look at how other plugins do it and copy their method

Comment: Then I would refer to how other plugins achieve it, edit: ^

Comment: That is indeed a good idea. I would take a look at that plugin

Comment: where are you putting the shortcode?

Comment: In the main file of my plugin I add the shortcodes